# Swift Core Data only saving relationship to the last in the loop

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode7, relationships

I have the following data model:

```
Checklist
@NSManaged var date: NSTimeInterval
@NSManaged var day: Int16
@NSManaged var items: NSSet?
```

and

```
ChecklistItem
@NSManaged var completed: Bool
@NSManaged var dayType: Int16
@NSManaged var itemName: String?
@NSManaged var timeOfDay: String?
@NSManaged var checklist: Checklist?
```

I am trying to save an array (NSSet) of ChecklistItems to a new Checklist object. Here is my code for doing that:

```
    var tasksHolder = [ChecklistItem]()

    let moc = CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext

    //puts one day's worth of tasks into the array
    for (index, item) in tasks.enumerate() {

        let newTask = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(String(ChecklistItem), inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! ChecklistItem
        newTask.completed = false
        newTask.dayType = DayType.ShakeDay.rawValue
        newTask.itemName = item
        newTask.timeOfDay = times[index]

        do {
            try moc.save()
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }

        tasksHolder.append(newTask)
    }

    //do each day
    for i in 0..<30 {

        let set = NSSet(array: tasksHolder)

        let newChecklist = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(String(Checklist), inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Checklist
        newChecklist.date = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        newChecklist.day = Int16(i)
        newChecklist.items = set

        do {
            try moc.save()
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

The actual Checklist objects are saving perfectly fine, it's the relationships that I'm having a problem with. The ChecklistItem relationship is only saving to the 30th (last) element of the Checklist. I'm not sure why this is happening, but I'm assuming that it has something to do with the way that I'm adding things to the Checklist object.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a side note, you should be able to remove the call to save from your for loop and place it just after completion of the loop which will save the context only once.

Comment: From both for loops?

Comment: Yes sorry, from both loops, calling it once, after completion of both loops.

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best option for what you have here, but you can add relationships in a nested for loop like below;

```
//do each day
for i in 0..<30 {

    let newChecklist = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(String(Checklist), inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Checklist
    newChecklist.date = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    newChecklist.day = Int16(i)

    for i in 0..<taskHolder.count {
        let items = newChecklist.mutableSetValueForKey("items")
        items.addObject(taskHolder[i])
    }

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Still didn't work :( It's only saving those checklist items to the last item still. All the others are faulted

Comment: Just realized you are adding same checklistItem to your checklists, so your checklist have multiple checklistItems and your checklistItems has multiple checklists, but you have one-to-many relationship. You need to have many-to-many relationship for this.

Comment: Ah, I think I may understand. So would I just update that in my database model and then regenerate the subclass?

Comment: Yes, when you update your data model to have many-to-many relationship between Checklist and ChecklistItem entities, everything should work fine.

Comment: Ok I'll try that and report back. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)